# /* ARGSUSED */ and other special comments

Tags: c, comments

I've searched on SO and googled but I don't get meanings of them. What are they and their purposes? When are they used? I think that maybe I'm too late to see them in modern-day programming and in my generation.

Some of them AFAIS,

- [/* ARGSUSED */](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-344.49/bsd/dev/ppc/cons.c)
- [/* VARARGS */](https://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-926/libiberty/concat.c)
- [/* LINTLIBRARY */](ftp://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/allData/gosta_plus/retired/L2/hdf/HDFlib/pc/src/mfhdf/libsrc/error.c)
- [/* NOSTRICT */](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LEONT/App-a2p-1.009/hash.c)

Example code with */* ARGSUSED */*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define TEN_MILLION 10000000L


/* ARGSUSED */
void *threadout(void *args) {
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    char *c;
    struct timespec sleeptime;

    sleeptime.tv_sec = 0;
    sleeptime.tv_nsec = TEN_MILLION;
    snprintf(buffer, BUFSIZE, "This is a thread from process %ld\n",
             (long)getpid());
    c = buffer;
    /*****************start of critical section ********************/
    while (*c != '\0') {
        fputc(*c, stderr);
        c++;
        nanosleep(&sleeptime, NULL);
    }
    /*******************end of critical section ********************/
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int error;
    int i;
    int n;
    pthread_t *tids;

    if (argc != 2){   /* check for valid number of command-line arguments */
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s numthreads\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    tids = (pthread_t *)calloc(n, sizeof(pthread_t));
    if (tids == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory for thread IDs");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (error = pthread_create(tids+i, NULL, threadout, NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread:%s\n", strerror(error));
            return 1;
        }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (error = pthread_join(tids[i], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to join thread:%s\n", strerror(error));
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are they '#define' flags for your specific libraries and such like?

Comment: `/* ARGSUSED */` appears to suppress the function parameter `args` not used warning.  I wonder why code did not use `void *threadout(void *args) { (void) args;` to do the same?

Answer (score 9):

it is specific to the `lint` to suppress comments about the particular issue

What is the lint - from wikipedia

> In computer programming, lint is a Unix utility that flags some
>   suspicious and non-portable constructs (likely to be bugs) in C
>   language source code; generically, lint or a linter is any tool that
>   flags suspicious usage in software written in any computer language.
>   The term lint-like behavior is sometimes applied to the process of
>   flagging suspicious language usage. Lint-like tools generally perform
>   static analysis of source code.
>
> Lint as a term can also refer more broadly to syntactic discrepancies
>   in general, especially in interpreted languages like JavaScript and
>   Python. For example, modern lint checkers are often used to find code
>   that doesn't correspond to certain style guidelines. Because these
>   languages lack a compiling phase that shows a list of errors prior to
>   execution, they can also be used as simple debuggers for common errors
>   (showing syntactic discrepancies as errors) or hard to find errors
>   such as heisenbugs (drawing attention on suspicious code as "possible
>   errors").

Item

Description

```
/*NOTREACHED*/  Suppresses comments about unreachable code.
/*VARARGSNumber*/   Suppresses checking the following old style function declaration for varying numbers of arguments, but does check the data type of the first Number arguments. If you do not include a value for Number, the lint command checks no arguments (Number=0). The ANSI function prototypes should use the ellipsis to indicate unspecified parameters rather than this comment mechanism.
/*ARGSUSED*/    Suppresses warnings about function parameters not used within the function definition.
/*LINTLIBRARY*/     If you place this comment at the beginning of a file, the lint command does not identify unused functions and function parameters in the file. This is used when running the lint command on libraries.
/*NOTUSED*/     Suppresses warnings about unused external symbols, functions and function parameters in the file beginning at its point of occurrence. This is a superset of the /*LINTLIBRARY*/ comment directive, but applies also to external symbols. It is useful for suppressing warnings about unused function prototypes and other external object declarations.
/*NOTDEFINED*/  Suppresses warnings about used, but undefined external symbols and functions in the file beginning at its point of occurrence.
/*LINTSTDLIB*/  Permits a standard prototype-checking library to be formed from header files by making function prototype declarations appear as function definitions. This directive implicitly activates both the /*NOTUSED*/ and /*LINTLIBRARY*/ comment directives to reduce warning noise levels.
```

Maybe other tools use them as well.

You may find another special comments as well. For example many IDEs have their own tokens placed in the comments - for example to add something to the TO DO List

Comment: Good answer. I wonder why the question was downvoted, given I don't find a duplicate...